# Parsing traceId, spanId from log line using Opentelemetry logprocessor

Tags: logging, open-telemetry

We need to parse attributes from log line so as to make them queryable on backends(eg: ES).

Now I tried using otel filelog receiver which supports stanza [operators](https://signoz.io/docs/userguide/logs/#operators-for-parsing-and-manipulating-logs), but the reason I had to drop it and replace log collection to fluentbit because filelog doesn't support multiline parsing.

Now I have a situation that I'm left with parsing/manipulating log at processors stage. For the same I wanted to use [logtransform processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/logstransformprocessor)

But unfortunately it seems it not part of otel-contrib distribution.

Otel collector contrib version: 0.68.0

Otel collector contrib config

```
 processor:
  logstransform:
    operators:
      - type: regex_parser
        id: trace_parser
        regex: 'traceId=(?P<trace_id>\S*)'
        parse_from: body
        trace:
          trace_id:
            parse_from: attributes.trace_id
```

Error:

```
2023/01/05 17:22:19 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'processors': unknown processors type: "logstransform" for id: "logstransform" (valid values: [attributes groupbytrace k8sattributes metricstransform probabilistic_sampler tail_sampling batch memory_limiter transform cumulativetodelta routing servicegraph span groupbyattrs resourcedetection experimental_metricsgeneration redaction resource spanmetrics deltatorate filter])
```

logline:
`[2022-12-30 12:34:56] [INFO] [Hotel Management System] traceId=4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736 spanId=00f067aa0ba902b7 message="Guest John Doe checked into room 214 for a 3-night stay." guestName=John Doe roomNumber=214 stayLength=3 night`

Expectation:

```
Resource SchemaURL: https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.6.1
Resource attributes:
     -> cloud.provider: Str(gcp)
     -> cloud.account.id: Str(project-jiomarket-non-prod)
     -> cloud.platform: Str(gcp_kubernetes_engine)
     -> cloud.region: Str(asia-south1)
     -> k8s.cluster.name: Str(cluster-central-alpha)
     -> host.id: Str(6758479764707402031)
ScopeLogs #0
ScopeLogs SchemaURL:
InstrumentationScope
LogRecord #0
ObservedTimestamp: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 18:22:02.466838531 +0000 UTC
SeverityText:
SeverityNumber: Unspecified(0)
Body: Str([2023-01-05 12:34:56] [INFO] [Hotel Management System] traceId=4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736 spanId=00f067aa0ba902b7 message="Guest John Doe checked into room 214 for a 3-night stay." guestName=John Doe roomNumber=214 stayLength=3 night
)
Attributes:
     -> fluent.tag: Str(kube.var.log.pods.newco_newcoshop-master-55c7f9d9f4-rmnqc_d02aa156-1671-4d58-b017-2e763b2d1683.newcoshop-master.test.log)
Trace ID: 4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736
Span ID: 00f067aa0ba902b7
Flags: 0
    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "logging"}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's currently not included in the latest builds of the distribution. I have opened a bug ticket for this [issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/17861).

Comment: I had to build collector manually to get logtransform. https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/custom-collector/